# Catalyst app using frameworks built for MacOS

Tags: react-native, macos, mac-catalyst

This might sound weird, as I don't have much experience with iOS / Mac development but is it possible to use frameworks built for Mac in a Mac Catalyst app?

I know , but I'm using React-Native to build a Mac Catalyst app and inside I want to use frameworks, specifically sound api frameworks built for Mac.